# Created a Task interface with an execute method. How can make it accept paramenters dynamically - JAVA

Tags: java

Interface

```
public interface ITask<T> {
    T execute() throws RemoteException, SQLException;
}
```

Its implementation

```
public interface IRMI extends Remote {
    <T> T executeTask(ITask<T> t) throws SQLException, RemoteException;
}
```

```
public <T> T executeTask(ITask<T> t) throws SQLException, RemoteException {
        return t.execute();
    }
```

so I want to have something like

```
public void  registerUserTask() throws SQLException, RemoteException {
        new CreateUser().execute(username, password, email);
    }
```

Comment: What type are the parameters you want to pass to `execute`? Will they always be `String`?

Comment: I iwant them to be of varying types cause in the end I would want to use doubles and integers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to change your `execute` method parameters from none that you have now to an array of parameters.

For example if you know that all the parameters you need to pass are `String`s you can change the execute method as:

```
public interface ITask<T> {
    T execute(String ... params) throws RemoteException, SQLException;
}
```

And in the implementation code of this interface you can access each parameter by its index e.g.

```
String firstParameter = params[0];
String secondParameter = params[1];
```

**UPDATE**

You can also change the method's signature to accept any Object as parameters e.g.

```
public interface ITask<T> {
    T execute(Object ... params) throws RemoteException, SQLException;
}
```

However you will have to explicitely cast each param to the Object type
e.g.

```
String firstParameter = (String) params[0];
Integer secondParameter = (Integer) params[1];
```

Comment: What if the params contain integers, strings, and doubles

Comment: You can change the method’s signature to execute(Object … params) instead of String

Comment: Works well. Cheers